# How to find all the palindromes in a large array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I need to find all the palindromes of `π` with 50 million digits `3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286...   (goes on and on...)`

I've stored all the digits of `π` in a char array. Now I need to search and count the number of 'palindromes' of length 2 to 15. For example, 535, 979, 33, 88, 14941, etc. are all valid results.

The final output I want is basically like the following.

```
Palindrome length           Number of Palindromes of this length
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   2                                  1234 (just an example)
   3                                  1245
   4                                  689
  ...                                 ...
  ...                                 ...
  ...                                 ...
  ...                                 ...
   15                                  0
```

pseudocode of my logic so far - it works but takes forever

```
//store all digits in a char array
char *piArray = (char *)malloc(NUM_PI_DIGITS * sizeof(char));
int count = 0; //count for the number of palindromes

//because we only need to find palindroms that are 2 - 15 digits long
for(int i = 2; i <= 15; i++){
     //loop through the piArray and find all the palindromes with i digits long
     for(int j = 0; j < size_of_piArray; j++){
            //check if the the sub array piArray[j:j+i] is parlindrom, if so, add a count
            bool isPalindrome = true;
            for (int k = 0; k < i / 2; k++)
            {
                if (piArray [j + k] != piArray [j + i - 1 - k])
                {
                    isPalindrom = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
             if(isPalindrome){
                  count++;
             }
     }
}
```

The problem I am facing now is that it takes too long to loop through the array of this large size `(15-2)=13` times. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Swapping the order of the loops should make your code run a lot faster because of caching

Comment: i think it would be more helpful for us if you showed us the rest of the code. so we could understand the algorithm better in order to improve it.

Comment: There is a lot of reundance in each iteration of your first loop, what you can do is check of every number if he is the center of a palindrom, and if so, of what length.

Comment: Does a number like 12321 count as two palindromes?

Comment: Re “of length 2 to 15”: You should have mentioned that in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71573124/how-to-create-a-char-array-with-large-size-say-50-million). When you only need to find palindromes of length 15, there is no reason to store all 50 million digits. You can scan the digits as you read them, and you only need to keep the most recent 15 digits.

Comment: https://mypastetext.com/raw/9f3eb2ipse ... in less than 5 seconds

Comment: @CaiusJard Nope, it is counted as one.

Comment: @JeanBouvattier What happens if the palindrome has an even length? For example, 33, 88

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did't know this when I asked my previous question, and I meant to find all the possible lengh. After I ran my program against first 100,000 digits, I found out that the length of palindromes  is about in range 2-15. For the simplicity of this question, I explicitly set it between 2 to 15.

Comment: @Ning: If you do not know the potential length of palindromes then you do need most of the digits. However, you do not need to check all possible lengths at all possible positions. For each position, check whether it is the center of a palindrome by checking whether the digit one position to its left equals the digit one position to its right. If not, there is no palindrome centered there. If so, continuing checking further positions until you find the length. Also check whether it is the near-center of an even-length palindrome by comparing it to the digit one position to its left…

Comment: … As before, if not, there is no palindrome centered there (between it and the one to its left). If they are equal, continuing checking neighboring digits to find the length. Be careful not to go beyond the left or right ends.

Comment: Note that if you know the number of digits, you do not need to keep them all in memory unless there is a palindrome centered in the middle that includes all of them. Once you read past the middle, possibilities for early digits to be part of a palindrome will drop away, depending on whether any incoming digits form a palindrome that can extend far back.

Comment: @Ning then you have a slightly different strategy for checking the palindrome:  incrementing `n` in`[i+n] == [i-1-n]` which is for a 123321 style palindrome, instead of`[i+1+n] == [i-1-n]`, which is for a 12321 style palindrome

Comment: @pmg I managed to do do it eventually and it takes about 25 seconds with about 10 seconds to find all the palindromes and the rest of the time to sort and calculate the distance. How did you do it so fast?

Comment: @Ning https://pastebin.com/8f431Me4

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it can't be done less than `O(len*n)`, and that you are doing this `O(len^2*n)`, where `2 <= len <= 15`, is almost the same since the `K` coefficient doesn't change the `O` notation in this case, but if you want to avoid this extra loop, you can check these links, it shouldn't be hard to add a counter for each length since these codes are counting all of them, with maximum possible length:
[source1](https://iq.opengenus.org/number-of-palindromic-substrings/), [source2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-palindrome-sub-strings-string/), [source3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-palindrome-sub-strings-string-set-2/).

***NOTE:*** Mostly it's better to reach out GeekForGeeks when you are looking for algorithms or optimizations.

***EDIT:*** one of the possible ways with `O(n^2)` time complexity and `O(n)`
Auxiliary Space. You can change unordered_map by array if you wish, anyway here the key will be the length and the value will be the count of palindromes with that length.

```
unordered_map<int, int> countPalindromes(string& s) {
    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        // check for odd length palindromes
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

            if (!s[i + j])
                break;

            if (s[i - j] == s[i + j]) {

                // check for palindromes of length
                // greater than 1
                if ((i + j + 1) - (i - j) > 1)
                    m[(i + j + 1) - (i - j)]++;

            } else
                break;
        }

        // check for even length palindromes
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (!s[i + j + 1])
                break;
            if (s[i - j] == s[i + j + 1]) {

                // check for palindromes of length
                // greater than 1
                if ((i + j + 2) - (i - j) > 1)
                    m[(i + j + 2) - (i - j)]++;

            } else
                break;
        }
    }
  
    return m;
}
```

Comment: It is better to import relevant code snippets from other sites rather than just link to them. The answer's usefulness is diminished (possibly to zero) if the linked page dies

Comment: @CaiusJard - well, never thought that way about links, but there is code too now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve it for C, as I'm a C# dev but I expect the conversion will be trivial - I've tried to keep it as basic as possible

```
    char[] pi = "3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286".ToCharArray(); //get a small piece as an array of char
    int[] lenCounts = new int[16]; //make a new int array with slots 0-15
    
    for(int i = 1; i < pi.Length-1; i++){

        if(pi[i+1] == pi[i-1]){ //center of an odd length pal
            int n = 2; 
            while(pi[i+n] == pi[i-n] && n <= 7) n++;
            lenCounts[((n-1)*2+1)]++;
            
        } else if(pi[i] == pi[i-1]){ //center of an even length pal
            int n = 1;
            while(pi[i+n] == pi[i-1-n] && n <= 7) n++;
            lenCounts[n*2]++;
            
        } 
            
            
    }
```

This demonstrates the "crawl the string looking for a palindrome center then crawl away from it in both directions looking for equal chars" technique..

..the only thing I'm not sure on, and it has occurred in the Pi posted, is what you want to do if palindromes overlap:

> 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716**93993**75105820974944592307816406286

This contains 939 and overlapping with it, 3993. The algo above will find both, so if overlaps are not to be allowed then you might need to extend it to deal with eliminating earlier palindromes if they're overlapped by a longer one found later

You can play with the c# version at https://dotnetfiddle.net/tkQzBq - it has some debug print lines in too. Fiddles are limited to a 10 second execution time so I don't know if you'll be able to time the full 50 megabyte  - you might have to run this algo locally for that one

Edit: fixed a bug in the answer but I haven't fixed it in the fiddle; I did have `while(.. n<lenCounts.Length)` i.e. allowing `n` to reach 15, but that would be an issue because it's in both directions.. `n`should go to 7 to remain in range of the counts array. I've patched that by hard coding 7 but you might want to make it dependent on array length/2 etc

Comment: Your approach is elegant and has good cache locality, which will improve the running speed significantly. The OP is supposed to count the palindromes, so yes they can overlap and the inner loops should be `while(n < lenCounts && pi[i+n] == pi[i-n]) { lenCounts[n * 2 + 1]++; n++; }` ...

Comment: I'm not sure about incrementing lenCounts in the while; OP mentioned that 12321 is just one palindrome [I assumed of length 5] rather than a 3 and a 5, for example.. Which was what led me to wonder about eg 12100121 - algo will find 121, 12100121 and another 121.

Comment: The `else` should be removed.

Comment: The OP not mentioning `494` is probably just an omission in a sample list of matches. The outer loop `for(int i = 2; i <= 15; i++){` seems to indicate that small palindromes are found and counted even if they are part of larger ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C version adapted from the approach proposed by *Caius Jard*:

```
void check_pi_palindromes(int NUM_PI_DIGITS, int max_length, int counts[]) {
    // store all digits in a char array
    int max_span = max_length / 2;
    int start = max_span;
    int end = NUM_PI_DIGITS + max_span;
    char *pi = (char *)malloc(max_span + NUM_PI_DIGITS + max_span);

    // read of generate the digits starting at position `max_span`
    [...]
    // clear an initial and trailing area to simplify boundary testing
    memset(pi, ' ', start);
    memset(pi + end, ' ', max_span);

    // clear the result array
    for (int i = 0; i <= max_length; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    // loop through the pi array and find all the palindromes 
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (pi[i + 1] == pi[i - 1]) { //center of an odd length palindrome
            count[3]++;
            for (n = 2; n <= max_span && pi[i + n] == pi[i - n]; n++) {
                count[n * 2 + 1]++;
            }
        }
        if (pi[i] == pi[i - 1]) { //center of an even length palindrome
            count[2]++;
            for (n = 1; n <= max_span && pi[i + n] == pi[i - n]; n++) {
                count[n * 2]++;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

For each position in the array, it scans in both directions for palindromes of odd and even lengths with these advantages:

- single pass through the array
- good cache locality because all reads from the array are in a small span from the current position
- fewer tests as larger palindromes are only tested as extensions of smaller ones.

A small working prefix and suffix is used to avoid the need to special case the beginning and end of the sequence.